# Drush ignoring `$options['config']` statement in drushrc file from the 'drush' folder at the root of the current git repository

Tags: drush

I'm a long-time browser, first-time poster.

I have a Drupal 7 site set-up using [Drupal-Boilerplate](https://github.com/Lullabot/drupal-boilerplate/tree/816bacab2abaec923c7c3c888a45639ad4c1cdb4) structure in a Git repository. I defined some settings in the `drush/drushrc.php` file. The [documentation](https://github.com/Lullabot/drupal-boilerplate/tree/816bacab2abaec923c7c3c888a45639ad4c1cdb4/drush) indicates:

> “Drush doesn't by default know to search this directory. To work around that we need to add this awesome snippet to our local drushrc.php file.”

I added the provided snippet to `docroot/sites/all/drush/drushrc.php`. But the `$options['config']` statement seems to be ignored. The settings defined in `drush/drushrc.php` are not taking effect.

I believe that the code is correctly defining the root of the Git repository. The `$options['alias-path']` statement seems to take effect as the “example” aliases appear when I run `drush site-alias`. The `$options['include']` statement also seems to take effect as the `devify` command defined in `drush/commands/build.drush.inc` is available.

The configuration options I have specified in `drush/drushrc.php` are not taking effect. When I run `drush status`, the “Drush configuration” lists `docroot/sites/all/drush/drushrc.php` and my user-specific `drushrc.php` from my home directory. I would expect to also see the `drush/drushrc.php` file listed.

I have tried executing `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`. That returns the correct path to the root of the Git repository. I tried explicitly adding the `drush/drushrc.php` file by adding the full path in an `$options['config']` statement in `docroot/sites/all/drush/drushrc.php`. None of that seems to have been effective.

I’m at my wits end with this. Please help me StackExchange!

I’m using

- Drush 6.3.0
- Drupal 7.28
- PHP 5.5.11
- Windows 8

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) As I understand the docs you need add the snippet to your local drushrc.php (i.e. the one in your home folder), and that will allow drush to discover a file in the _root_ of your Drupal installation (not in sites/all). Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Thanks, @Clive. If I’m interpreting the code correctly, the snippet should point Drush at the root of the Git repository as captured in `$repo`. But, even still, specifying the file path of the drushrc.php file to include did not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

As Clive said, the snipped goes in $HOME/.drush/drushrc.php, not in the drushrc.php file in your site folder.  The drushrc.php in your site folder does not get parsed until Drush bootstraps your site; by that time, it's too late to add items to the 'config' list, as it has already been processed.

Also, in place of:

`$repo_dir = drush_get_option('root') ? drush_get_option('root') : getcwd();`

... it would probably be better if the snippet used:

`$repo_dir = drush_get_context('DRUSH_SELECTED_DRUPAL_ROOT') ? drush_get_context('DRUSH_SELECTED_DRUPAL_ROOT') : getcwd();`

Finally, rather than setting the 'config' option, which is gitchy and a little high-strung, you could just include your drushrc.php directly.

Replace:

`$options['config'] = $repo . '/drush/drushrc.php';`

with:

`include $repo . '/drush/drushrc.php';`

Then you could go back to putting this snippet in your sites/all/drush/drushrc.php, if that's working better for you.

Comment: Thanks, @greg_l_anderson. Based on your answer and @Clive’s, adding the snippet to my local file without the snippet in `sites/all` eliminated the aliases and commands. Adding the snippet in both my local file and `sites/all` was the same behavior as reported in my original question. Drush seems to be processing the snippet and finding the path. Otherwise I wouldn’t have the aliases, right? I thought you might be on to something when you mention “it’s too late” to affect the 'config' list.